# Determine the dual cone $\mathbb{K}^{*}$ of the following cones?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

a) $ \mathbb{K} = \mathbb{R}_{+}^{n}$

b) $ \mathbb{K} = \mathbb{S}_{+}^{n}$

c) $ \mathbb{K} = \{(x,t) | \begin{Vmatrix}
x
\end{Vmatrix}_{2} \leq t\}, x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}, t \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$

This is book convex optimization.

Comment: By the way, these cones are called: a) The nonnegative orthant; b) The positive semidefinite cone; c) the second-order cone (or the ``ice cream cone").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\mathbb{R^n}$ is considered as Hilbert space with the standard scalar product $(\cdot,\cdot)$, the dual cone $K^\ast$ to a given cone $K$ is usually defined as
$$
K^\ast=\{y \in \mathbb{R^n} \mid \forall x\in K:(x,y)\ge 0\}.
$$
For example let $K=\mathbb{R^n}_+$. Then $y \in K^\ast$ means
$$
(x,y)=\sum_{k=1}^n x_ky_k \ge 0 ~ for ~ all ~ x_1,\dots ,x_n \ge 0. 
$$
Clearly $y \in K$ implies $y \in K^\ast$.
Reversely, let $\{ e_1,\dots,e_n \}$ be the standard base of $\mathbb{R^n}$. Now
$$
y \in K^\ast ~ \Rightarrow ~ y_k=(e_k,y) \ge 0 ~ (k=1,\dots,n) ~ \Rightarrow ~ y \in K.
$$
Thus, in this case $K^\ast = K$. Of course, in general $K \not= K^\ast$.